# SignTool Error --> I cannot create a package for my application and only this app

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, signtool

```
 1>  IPC-ACE -> C:\Users\Samer.Chemaly\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\IPC-ACE-1\IPC-ACE\bin\x86\Release\IPC-ACE.exe
 1>MakePRI : warning 0xdef00520: Invalid qualifier: 12-SEC
 1>  IPC-ACE -> C:\Users\samer.chemaly\Desktop\ACE-IPC\IPC-ACE_1.1.0.2_x86_Test\IPC-ACE_1.1.0.2_x86.appx
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1772,9): error APPX1204: Failed to sign 'C:\Users\samer.chemaly\Desktop\ACE-IPC\IPC-ACE_1.1.0.2_x86_Test\IPC-ACE_1.1.0.2_x86.appx'. SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1772,9): error APPX1204: 
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 2 failed ===========
```

This is the error I am getting when I try to create the app package.

Comment: I wonder if Signtool doesn't have permission to write there? Maybe try running VS as administrator? It could also be an issue where VS opens a stream to the file and doesn't close it. Try restarting VS.

Comment: It did not work. Same error as before: 
 Error 8 Failed to sign 'C:\Users\samer.chemaly\Desktop\ACE-IPC\IPC-ACE_1.1.0.3_x86_Test\IPC-ACE_1.1.0.3_x86.appx'. SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
 IPC-ACE

Comment: The Thing is that  if I try deploying the package of any other application new or old it works perfectly. Only this app is showing the mentioned issue.

Comment: Try setting the build output to Verbose, Detailed, or Diagnostic. This may give some more information on what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was strange! I recreated the app and started to create items page by page and item by item. The issue was in a presentation file available in the assets with and extension .exe
The error that was showing is irrelevant at all but this is for you to know in case you face a similar issue. thank you :)